# Is it possible to have a higher train error than a test error in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, overfitting, training-error

Usually it is called over-fitting when the test error is higher than the training error. Does that imply that it is called under-fitting when the training error is higher than the test error? Also what is the difference between test error and validation error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These simplified formulae from Stanley Сhan's *Introduction to Probability for Data Science* provide some good intuition on the train/test error:

MSE<sub>train</sub> = σ<sup>2</sup> (1 - d/N)

MSE<sub>test</sub> = σ<sup>2</sup> (1 + d/N)

where **σ<sup>2</sup>** is noise variance (data measurement errors and such), **N** is the sample size, **d** is a measure of model complexity (d<=N).

Overfitting means that a model fits too closely to the training samples so that it fails to generalize (d is comparable to N): train error is low, test error is high.
When the model is too simple and uderfits data (d<<N), train and test error are about equally high.

When your test error is suspiciously low, that likely means you've got some sort a of data leakage from a test set (e.g. when you preprocess a whole dataframe before splitting).

As of validation vs test error, a separate validation split normally serves as an intermediate test for e.g. best model/hyperparameter selection. Since you purposely select what performs best on this set, it can be treated as a sort of leakage as well. Thus the final test data should remain unseen until the very end of the model development process.